# ToYAML instances for Map and StrMap

Tags: generics, yaml, purescript

The [purescript-yaml](https://github.com/archaeron/purescript-yaml) library defines `ToYAML` instances for simple types such as `Tuple`, `Array` etc.

How can I obtain or derive a `ToYAML` instance for `Map` or `StrMap`? 
I read somewhere that `purescript-generics-rep` could be used, but how?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work to convert `StrMap a`...

```hs
import Data.Map as M
import Data.StrMap as StrMap

instance strMapToYAML :: (ToYAML a) => ToYAML (StrMap a) where
  toYAML strMap = YObject $ StrMap.fold (\acc key value ->
    M.insert key (toYAML value) acc
  ) M.empty strMap
```

The current implementation use `YObject` as an type alias for `Map String YValue`  So this instance converts the `StrMap a` into a `Map String YValue`, and then wraps it using the `YObject` data constructor.

An instance for `Map a b` could be defined similarly, but you'd have to make sure `a` can be converted into a string, and `b` can be converted into a `YValue`.

Edit - I just realized you will have an orphan instance if you try and put this in your own code.  This will need to go in the core library. You can either wait for a pull request to the author, or fork the repo and add that instance to the Data.YAML.Foreign.Encode module.